# How can I repair a float valve that is blocked open?

Tags: bathroom, toilet, valve

The toilet float valve I use is of the brand Geberit.
It keeps leeking water because it does not close anymore.

I guess the metal pin at the front needs to move when the green elements move up.
Does anyone have some ideas what I can do to make it work?
I tried pushing and pulling it gently, but it looks very fragile so I don't think it's a good idea.
I've also put it in vinegar for a night, without any success.

[image: float valve]

Comment: Have you checked the washers and other valve parts? These valves tend to be replaced when they fail since replacements are very affordable. Also, double check your water pressure when the toilet is leaking, these tend to be the first valves to go when your water pressure is too high.

Answer (score 1):

I bought a new valve and replaced it.
All works fine now.